# Python cannot compare datetime and method

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I tried to convert two columns to the same format, datetime in this case.

```
a['sale_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(a['sale_date'])
a['last_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(a['last'])
a[a.last_date>a.sale_date]
```

When I output the dtypes they both show up as the same:

```
sale_date                            datetime64[ns]
last_date                                 datetime64[ns]
```

But I get an error from the comparison of sale_date with last that says:
`Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and method`
Does this mean they are different types? Why does this not show up when I use .dtypes? Visually the outputs look comparable.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `a[a.last_date>a.sale_date]` be `a['last_date'] > a['sale_date']` if you are comparing two items in a dictionary?

Comment: Minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Anonymous It's not a dictionary. Those are columns in a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: @user13948 Are you still getting the same error after changing the column name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html#pandas-dataframe-last) is the name of an existing `pandas` method. So, it is better to avoid using `last` as a column name. If you can't avoid it, then you have to select the column using square brackets.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'sale_date': pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=4, freq='3D'),
                  'last': pd.date_range('2018-04-12', periods=4, freq='1D')})
a[a["last"] > a.sale_date]
#    sale_date       last
# 0 2018-04-09 2018-04-12
# 1 2018-04-12 2018-04-13
```